# Python read file into 2d list

Tags: python

I have a txt file like this:

```
1 3 4
5 5 6
```

and I want to parse it elements to a tuple or a list accordingly. So far I was able to read the file line by line but the result is not what I want

```
    ins = open( "input.txt", "r" )
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        array.append( line )
    ins.close()
    print array
```

however printing the array I get

```
['1 3 4', '5 5 6']
```

what I want is

```
[[1, 3, 4], [5, 5, 6]]
```

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: What does this have to do with tuples?

Comment: what do you mean by `[1 3 4]`? this is not a valid python expression. did you mean `[1,3,4]`?

Comment: Yeah you are right! This is what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you're looking for the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of `str` objects. You probably also want to use the `int` type to get actual numbers, instead of strings:

```
data = []
for line in ins:
    number_strings = line.split() # Split the line on runs of whitespace
    numbers = [int(n) for n in number_strings] # Convert to integers
    data.append(numbers) # Add the "row" to your list.
print(data) # [[1, 3, 4], [5, 5, 6]]
```

The following line does the same thing, but in a more compact and Pythonic fashion:

```
data = [[int(n) for n in line.split()] for line in ins]
```

---

Finally, if you really want to use tuples instead of lists, it's just a matter of using the `tuple` type on the inner list:

```
data = [tuple(int(n) for n in line.split()) for line in ins]
print(data) # [(1, 3, 4), (5, 5, 6)]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as file:
    result = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in file]
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner time:

```
[line.split() for line in ins]
```

If you want to convert items to `int` feel free to do so:

```
[map(int, line.split()) for line in ins]
```

Comment: @tim So what? The asker isn't having trouble reading the file.

Comment: That doesn't justify the lack of a complete answer. Adding that other line takes 10 seconds and avoids confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = [map(int, line.split()) for line in f]
```

This is more or less equivalent to the more verbose:

```
try:
    f = open('input.txt', 'r')
    data = []
    for line in f:
        data.append([int(n) for n in line.split()])
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

this works

For lists:

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as ins:
    array = [[int(n) for n in line.split()] for line in ins]
```

example output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

or for tuples:

```
 with open('yourfile.txt', 'r') as ins:
     myTuple = tuple(tuple(int(n) for n in line.split()) for line in ins)
```

example output:

```
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))
```

using `with` means that your file is opened only for the statements
within the block, and is then automatically closed. This is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
txt='''\
1 3 4
5 5 6'''

print [[int(s) for s in line.split()] for line in txt.splitlines()]
# [[1, 3, 4], [5, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the output as you show it, with no single quotes and no commas between the numbers, you can just change your last line, `print array`, to this:

```
print str(["[%s]"%item for item in array]).replace("'","")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways...

```
def read_text(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        line_array = file.read().splitlines()
        cell_array = []
        for line in line_array:
            cell_array.append(line.split())
        return cell_array
```

A little compression :

```
def read_text(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        line_array = file.read().splitlines()
        cell_array = [line.split() for line in line_array]
        return cell_array
```

**Even more compression !**

```
def read_text(path):
    return [[item for item in line.split()] for line in open(path)]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
n = int(input())
l = []
for i in range(n):
    l.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split(" "))))
```