# How do I add my x and y coordinates into list from a text file?

Tags: python

hi im using python on jupyter notebook and i want to know how to add the x and y coordinates to a list from a text file containing coordinates into list.

The list is called citylist=[]
filename is cities8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgx3C.png)

how do i append these coordinates into a list.
Thank you so much for your time guys.

Comment: You're asking how to read a file, and it's a duplicate.

Comment: Please post text here and code-format it rather than using screenshots.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read file into 2d list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238242/python-read-file-into-2d-list)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is separated by white spaces this can be done as follows:

```
with open('FILE_NAME_GOES_HERE', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

x_coordinates = []
y_coordinates = []

for line in data:
    _, x, y = line.split()
    x_coordinates.append(int(x))
    y_coordinates.append(int(y))
```

You can get the idea from here and make your own list in whatever format you want

Answer (score -1):

More functional approach would look like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from functools import reduce
from operator import itemgetter

cities_list = []

coordinates = namedtuple('coordinates', 'x y')
getter = itemgetter(slice(1, 3))


def pipe(*funcs): return lambda data: reduce(lambda a, b: b(a), funcs, data)


def split(s): return s.split(' ')


def map_int(lst): return map(int, lst)


def build_coordinates(args): return coordinates(*args)


def append(val): cities_list.append(val)


row_pipe = pipe(str.strip, split, map_int, list, getter, build_coordinates, append)

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    [row_pipe(r) for r in iter(f.readline, '')]

print(cities_list)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

First of all you have to read that file and split it using newline

```
citylist=[]
cities = open("cities8.txt", "r")
coordinates = cities.read().split("\n") # this will read and split file
cities.close() # close the file 
for city in coordinates:
    citylist.append(city.split(" ")[1:])
```

Now to print coordinates you can loop through the list

```
for i in citylist:
   print(f"X:{i[0]}, Y:{i[1]}")
```